# Maharatz Chiyus's List of Unobserved Laws

Tags: minhag, halacha-theory, ashkenazi, talmud-bavli, maharatz-chiyus

I believe the *Maharatz Chiyus* has a list of Talmudic laws that, at least in his day, had ceased to be observed in Ashkenazic communities, except perhaps by the most scrupulous (e.g. *yoshon*, *eruv*, *ribis l'nochri*).  I can't seem to find it and was wondering if anyone knew where it is (e.g. what volume/page of *Kol Sifrei Maharatz Chiyus*.

[Bonus question: I believe it is cited in a responsum of Rav Nachum Rabinovitch, *shelit"a*, in his *Shu"t Siach Nachum*, though I don't seem to be able to locate that either.]

Comment: Try Siach Nachum 38

Comment: Not all your examples work. E.g. by "Eruv" you mean community eruvim based on the 60 ribo requirement for a real reshus harabbim. If so, the Vatican manuscript has a line that implies this was a given. http://eruvonline.blogspot.com/2006/01/part-2-shishim-ribo-mystery-solved.html

Comment: And ribis lenokhri and mayim acharonim appear to be specifically Bavli rulings, where Ashkenazim are following the Yerushalmi. The dominant thuoght among historians of halakhah is that Ashkenaz contains a richer mix of refugees from Israel, where Sepharad is more exclusively Bavli. And that therefore some rulings in shas simply never got accepted. You "ceased to be observed" assumes Ashkenazim ever did. And for many of these things, that's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book published in English, The Student's Guide Through The Talmud, by Zevi Hirsch Chajes, translated, Edited and Critically Annotated by Jacob Shachter, ISBN 1-966143-05-3. See Chapter 13: Enactments The Binding Force Of Which Was Later Relaxed. (In response to your actual question: I assume that this chapter is an English translation of matter that the author published somewhere else, but I don't know anything about that. Chapters 17 through 32, minus section 26, appear at the beginning of Ein Ya'akov.)

Comment: Chaim, thanks for finding this source! Instead of pasting in images of a whole chapter thereof, which we probably don't have license to do, could you please [edit] in a description of how well the information in that chapter matches what the question here is looking for? Please take a look at [our guideline](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-should-i-cite-an-answer-elsewhere/76#76) for citing sources.

Comment: I wondered about this. I could have simply given the publication data, or I could have pasted in the whole chapter; but no middle course presented itself. The whole chapter is the answer to the question. What do you think of the publication data plus an image of one page, to illustrate the sort of material?

Comment: Chaim, a summary/description would be far superior to an image, as you would tailor it to be useful to this question and because it would be readable by blind people and search engines.